# PHP automatic list creation from a textfile to (X)HTML

Tags: php, html, html-lists

I'm creating a CMS as you might already know, and now I have a lil' problem.

Lets say:
I have a textfile containing this:

```
[b]Some bold text[/b]
[i]Italic[/i]
- List item 1
- List item 2
- List item 3
# List item 1
# List item 2
# List item 3
```

And I want to convert it to:

```
<b>Some bold text</b>
<i>Italic</i>
<ul>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <li>List item 3</li>
</ul>
<ol>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <li>List item 3</li>
</ol>
```

The bold and italic work (with regexes), but how do I do the lists?

The '-' list should be transformed to

```
<ul>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <li>List item 3</li>
</ul>
```

And the '#' list to

```
<ol>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <li>List item 3</li>
</ol>
```

Does anybody have experience with this? Please help me. I'm using PHP 5.2.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use an existing parsing library, you have to parse the file line by line, and to keep the current state somewhere.

If the lines starts with " - ", and the state tells you that you're not already in a list, put a <ul> plus a <li>. If you're already in a list, just put the <li>.

Same thing with lines starting with " # ".

Comment: Thanks, I dont prefer those libraries because they are about 18kb which is too big. I think I'll start list items with </li><li> to make valid XHTML.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using another markup language such as [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) or [Textile](http://textism.com/tools/textile/).  Then you would just have to deal with a library.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't prefer libs. They are far too big in file size. My CMS may not exceed 3000 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you don't need all of Markdown...
but why not just take the functionality you need?

I adapted the list-processing functions to work procedurally.
To minimize file size, I compressed the verbose regexes
and removed comments related to other Markdown.
It clocks in at 3308 bytes.

Maybe it's still too bloated for your taste... d-:
but you're free to cut more corners and remove stuff.
For example, maybe you don't need nested lists.

The modified code is below.
Here's the license first:

> PHP Markdown
> Copyright (c) 2004-2009 Michel Fortin
> http://michelf.com/
> All rights reserved.
>
> Based on Markdown
> Copyright (c) 2003-2006 John Gruber
> http://daringfireball.net/
> All rights reserved.
>
> Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
> modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are
> met:
>
> - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
>   this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
> - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
>   notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
>   documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
> - Neither the name "Markdown" nor the names of its contributors may
>   be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software
>   without specific prior written permission.
>
> This software is provided by the copyright holders and contributors "as
> is" and any express or implied warranties, including, but not limited
> to, the implied warranties of merchantability and fitness for a
> particular purpose are disclaimed. In no event shall the copyright owner
> or contributors be liable for any direct, indirect, incidental, special,
> exemplary, or consequential damages (including, but not limited to,
> procurement of substitute goods or services; loss of use, data, or
> profits; or business interruption) however caused and on any theory of
> liability, whether in contract, strict liability, or tort (including
> negligence or otherwise) arising in any way out of the use of this
> software, even if advised of the possibility of such damage.

```
<?php
@define('MARKDOWN_TAB_WIDTH', 4);
$tab_width = MARKDOWN_TAB_WIDTH;
$list_level = 0;

function doLists($text) {
# Form HTML ordered (numbered) and unordered (bulleted) lists.
    global $tab_width, $list_level;
    $less_than_tab = $tab_width - 1;
    # Re-usable patterns to match list item bullets and number markers:
    $marker_ul_re  = '[*-]';
    $marker_ol_re  = '\d+[\.]';
    $marker_any_re = "(?:$marker_ul_re|$marker_ol_re)";
    $markers_relist = array(
        $marker_ul_re => $marker_ol_re,
        $marker_ol_re => $marker_ul_re,
        );
    foreach ($markers_relist as $marker_re => $other_marker_re) {
        # Re-usable pattern to match any entirel ul or ol list:
        $whole_list_re = '((([ ]{0,'.$less_than_tab.'})('.$marker_re.')[ ]+)(?s:.+?)(\z|\n{2,}(?=\S)(?![ ]*'.$marker_re.'[ ]+)|(?=\n\3'.$other_marker_re.'[ ]+)))'; // mx
        # We use a different prefix before nested lists than top-level lists.
        # See extended comment in _ProcessListItems().
        if ($list_level) {
            $text = preg_replace_callback('{
                    ^
                    '.$whole_list_re.'
                }mx',
                '_doLists_callback', $text);
            }
        else {
            $text = preg_replace_callback('{
                    (?:(?<=\n)\n|\A\n?) # Must eat the newline
                    '.$whole_list_re.'
                }mx',
                '_doLists_callback', $text);
            }
        }
    return $text;
    }

function _doLists_callback($matches) {
# Re-usable patterns to match list item bullets and number markers:
    $marker_ul_re  = '[*+-]';
    $marker_ol_re  = '\d+[\.]';
    $marker_any_re = "(?:$marker_ul_re|$marker_ol_re)";
    $list = $matches[1];
    $list_type = preg_match("/$marker_ul_re/", $matches[4]) ? "ul" : "ol";
    $marker_any_re = ( $list_type == "ul" ? $marker_ul_re : $marker_ol_re );
    $list .= "\n";
    $result = processListItems($list, $marker_any_re);
    $result = "<$list_type>\n" . $result . "</$list_type>";
    return "\n". $result ."\n\n";
    }

function processListItems($list_str, $marker_any_re) {
#   Process the contents of a single ordered or unordered list, splitting it
#   into individual list items.
# The $list_level global keeps track of when we're inside a list.
# Each time we enter a list, we increment it; when we leave a list,
# we decrement. If it's zero, we're not in a list anymore.
    global $list_level;
    $list_level++;
# trim trailing blank lines:
    $list_str = preg_replace("/\n{2,}\\z/", "\n", $list_str);
    $list_str = preg_replace_callback('{(\n)?(^[ ]*)('.$marker_any_re.'(?:[ ]+|(?=\n)))((?s:.*?))(?:(\n+(?=\n))|\n)(?= \n* (\z | \2 ('.$marker_any_re.') (?:[ ]+|(?=\n))))}xm','_processListItems_callback', $list_str);
    $list_level--;
    return $list_str;
    }

function _processListItems_callback($matches) {
    $item = $matches[4];
    $leading_line =& $matches[1];
    $leading_space =& $matches[2];
    $marker_space = $matches[3];
    $tailing_blank_line =& $matches[5];
    if ($leading_line || $tailing_blank_line
    || preg_match('/\n{2,}/', $item))
        { # Replace marker with the appropriate whitespace indentation
        $item = $leading_space . str_repeat(' ', strlen($marker_space)) . $item;
        $item = outdent($item)."\n";
        }
    else { # Recursion for sub-lists:
        $item = doLists(outdent($item));
        $item = preg_replace('/\n+$/', '', $item);
        }
    return "<li>" . $item . "</li>\n";
    }

function outdent($text) {
# Remove one level of line-leading tabs or spaces
    global $tab_width;
    return preg_replace('/^(\t|[ ]{1,'.$tab_width.'})/m', '', $text);
    }
?>
```

Comment: By the way -- a CMS in PHP with a constraint of 3000 *bytes*?!  
Yowza, that'd be impressive. So have you finished and are you sharing?  I'd be particularly interested in a lighter-weight list-parsing function, if you wrote a good one based on FWH's suggestion. Cheers.